# Compile Vala from Linux for Windows

Tags: gcc, vala, mingw-w64

I usually only code in high level code so I have no experience at all compiling code (as the IDE usually does this for me) so I could be overlooking something very obvious.
I've spent a lot of time figuring out how to compile Vala in Linux but I don't seem to be able to make this work.

These are the steps I took:

1. I installed valac, gtk, mingw64 (I've built a docker image just to make sure: 0620731/valac:mingw64)
2. Copied some working vala code from a gnome tutorial showing off gtk3.
3. Ran this: valac --cc=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 --pkg gtk+-3.0 -X -mwindows ../main.vala (I tried different compilers too. Results varied, but nothing good.)

The output I got was:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /home/developer/vala/Documents/Projects/gamedev/vala-test/bin/main.vala.c:6:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h: In function '_GLIB_CHECKED_ADD_U64':
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:241:53: error: size of array '_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0' is negative
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                                     ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:238:47: note: in definition of macro 'G_PASTE_ARGS'
 #define G_PASTE_ARGS(identifier1,identifier2) identifier1 ## identifier2
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:241:44: note: in expansion of macro 'G_PASTE'
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                            ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:423:3: note: in expansion of macro 'G_STATIC_ASSERT'
   G_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof (unsigned long long) == sizeof (guint64));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:46:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from /home/developer/vala/Documents/Projects/gamedev/vala-test/bin/main.vala.c:10:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h: At top level:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h:75:1: error: unknown type name 'uid_t'
 uid_t            g_credentials_get_unix_user      (GCredentials    *credentials,
 ^~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h:79:52: error: unknown type name 'uid_t'; did you mean 'pid_t'?
                                                    uid_t           uid,
                                                    ^~~~~
                                                    pid_t
error: cc exited with status 256
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

I also tried compiling the c file but I got the exact same results, so it's not a buggy version.

I managed to compile the same project on Windows though, so not all is lost, but I really want to be able to do this without a dual-boot/VM.
I'm so close, I don't want to quit this now.

This might be usefull (main.vala):

```
using Gtk;

int main(string[] args) {
    Gtk.init(ref args);

    var window = new Window();
    window.title = "First GTK+ Program";
    window.border_width = 10;
    window.window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER;
    window.set_default_size(350, 70);
    window.destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit);

    var button = new Button.with_label("Click me!");
    button.clicked.connect(() => {
        button.label = "Thank you";
    });

    window.add(button);
    window.show_all();

    Gtk.main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable.

Comment: What did I do wrong then? I read both documents, but I don't see it. Is it too technical? I presume that the line "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague" kind of sums it all up, but this is how I would go about that. :/

Comment: where is the code here? only error trace has been posted.It should be reproducible if possible so that others can help

Comment: whoops! I didn't pay attention to that. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with the libraries used. `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and `/usr/include/` are the paths for native libraries. The `pkg-config` tool sorts this out for you. So when calling `valac` also pass the right `pkg-config`:

```
valac --cc x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 \
      --pkg-config x86_64-w64-mingw32-pkg-config \
      --pkg gtk+-3.0 \
      -X -mwindows \
      ../main.vala
```

The next step is then make sure you have cross-compiled libraries installed on your Linux machine. It will depend on the Linux distribution you are using, for example with Fedora you will likely need to install:

```
dnf install mingw64-gtk3 mingw64-glib2
```

Finally, to make things easier to distribute, you may want to try static linking so everything is lumped together in one big binary. In Fedora there is a `glib2-static` package, but the problem is there doesn't seem to be static builds for GTK3. Otherwise take a look at [How to distribute a GTK+ application on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092784/how-to-distribute-a-gtk-application-on-windows) for some tips on the dynamic libraries you need to package.

Unfortunately none of this is tested - I don't have Windows to try this. It would be great to have a working procedure for cross-compiling Vala applications to run on Windows. Thanks for putting the effort in to get this far and it would be useful to know if you get it working.

Comment: This works! I didn't get it to work on ubuntu immediatly but I thought: "hey, it docker! Let's change my image to fedora", so I just copy-pasted your answer and it works. It's even a smaller binary than the one compiled on Windows. And I'll definitely take a look at static linking.