# Problems with deploying a GTK Application

Tags: windows, gtk, mingw, glib, msys2

I am currently testing the GTK Application that I built on windows using the MSYS2 64bit shell.

For the program to be able to run outside of the shell, I packed all the required DLLs with it as well as the following:

```
FOLDER\lib\gdk-pixbuf-2.0\2.10.0\loaders\\*
FOLDER\lib\gdk-pixbuf-2.0\2.10.0\loaders.cache
FOLDER\share\glib-2.0\schemas\gschemas.compiled 
FOLDER\share\icons\Adwaita\\*
FOLDER\share\icons\hicolor\\*
```

The good news is: It works :) And it also works flawlessly on another PC that doesnt have GTK/Msys2/whatever installed.

The bad news is: On yet another PC (I have tested it on 2 other Systems other than my developing System so far, one one of them it works flawlessly), the program itself works, but the GUI is not rendered sharply (texts are blurry).

Do you guys have any idea on what could be the reason for that? I'm guessing it could be one of the following:

- The affected system could have some general display problems that have nothing to do with my app.
- The gschemas.compiled file does not suit the affected system. In that case I would probably have to create that file dynamically, but I have no idea how to do this.
- I am missing some file from GTK or Glib that would solve the problem.

I am thankful for any help :) Compiling/Deploying a GTK App for Windows has proven to be a pain in the ***, but since (almost) everything works now, I feel like its not much that I am missing unless I have overseen something critical.

Regards,

tagelicht

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to distribute a GTK+ application on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092784/how-to-distribute-a-gtk-application-on-windows)

Comment: I dont think so because this question asks for DLLs which I have no problems with (atleast not anymore, partially thanks to the specified question :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the way you created your package, my bet is that you are missing some components, making the drawing code use some fallback routines, hence the "sharp" drawing.
Try to run the application in command line on the machine where your have the problem, to see if there are some unusual warnings you don't have when running it on your machine.

See also my answer on [how to distribute a GTK+ application on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49107236/518853).

Comment: Ill just mark this as accepted for now. Thanks for your input - but I'm still not sure what exactly causes the problem. However, I have tested my program on a couple of machines so far and none have had any problems other than the computer described in the question. So Im guessing it might be some local problem on that machine - I have inspected it a little bit further and while no such messages occur when starting it on the command line, I have noticed that some (not all) programs have that blurry look aswell - which really makes me think something must be wrong on that computer.

Comment: Right, if you have the same problem with other applications on that computer, then that may be a problem with the computer and not with your application bundle. Have you tried running another GTK+-based program on it, like GIMP? It probably won't be the same GTK+ version that will be used, but if you have the same problem, then the computer (drivers maybe?) is probably at fault. If not, then maybe there's more to dig.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, but I will give it a shot :) I will post updates here.