# gtkmm not found in MinGW despite being installed

Tags: c++, mingw, gtk3, gtkmm3

I am trying to compile following simple file (demo code from one of the tutorial sites) but `gtkmm.h` is not being found despite being installed.

```
$ cat rngtk1.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>
int
main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
 try {
  Gtk::Main m( argc, argv ) ;
  Gtk::Window win ;
  m.run( win ) ;
 }
 catch( std::exception const & exc ) {
  std::cout << exc.what() << std::endl ;
  exit( -1 ) ;
 }
 exit( 0 ) ;
}
```

On giving compile command:

```
$ g++ rngtk1.cpp
rngtk1.cpp:2:10: fatal error: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <gtkmm.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Changing to "gtkmm.h" does not help

Following show relevant packages are installed:

```
$ pacman -Ss gtkmm
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gtkmm 2.24.5-2
    C++ bindings for gtk2 (mingw-w64)
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gtkmm3 3.24.1-1
    C++ bindings for gtk3 (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtkmm 2.24.5-2
    C++ bindings for gtk2 (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtkmm3 3.24.1-1 [installed] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< NOTE
    C++ bindings for gtk3 (mingw-w64)

$ pacman -Ss gtk3
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gtk3 3.24.10-3
    GObject-based multi-platform GUI toolkit (v3) (mingw-w64)
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gtkmm3 3.24.1-1
    C++ bindings for gtk3 (mingw-w64)
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-spice-gtk 0.37-1
    GTK3 widget for SPICE clients (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3 3.24.10-3 [installed] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< NOTE
    GObject-based multi-platform GUI toolkit (v3) (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtkmm3 3.24.1-1 [installed] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< NOTE
    C++ bindings for gtk3 (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-spice-gtk 0.37-1
    GTK3 widget for SPICE clients (mingw-w64)
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include files for the package are not in the default search path. You will need to provide them via the compiler flags `-I`. As they are many, the easiest way that works for me in MSYS2 is using `pkg-config`, which will output all needed flags both for compilation and linking:

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags gtkmm-3.0) -c rngtk1.cpp -o rngtk1.o
g++ rngtk1.o $(pkg-config --libs gtkmm-3.0) -o rngtk1.exe
```

Comment: Yes, it creates an executable, but the exe file does not run since it does not find `libgtkmm-3.0-1.dll`. Where can I find this file?

Comment: The library `libgtkmm-3.0-1.dll` is in `/mingw64/bin`, which is added automatically to `$PATH` when I start MSYS2 using the "*MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit*" launcher in the Start menu. If you start your MSYS2 shell in some other way, you will need to add `/mingw64/bin` to `$PATH` by hand.

Comment: I meant executable does not run when transferred to other Windows system. Copying `libgtkmm-3.0-1.dll` with exe file leads to error showing many dll are missing. Do I need to copy all these dll also when distributing my exe file to my friends? Is there any way to statically link all needed dll files with the exe file?

Comment: Yes, I believe that the most common approach is to bundle those DLLs with your application, but you may also need other files. Gtk+ is big. This seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092784/how-to-distribute-a-gtk-application-on-windows