# How do I distribute a Gtkmm application on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, deployment, gtk, gtkmm

I have written a GUI using gtkmm (the C++ language wrapper for GTK+). I have been able to find the .dlls that the .exe. file depends upon, and make a basic installer using NSIS. However, I am having trouble distributing the application to other Windows devices. As I am completely new to this, does anyone have advice as to how to properly distribute the application? All I really need to do is download it on a few other PCs. Thanks!

Comment: You need to distribute your compilers runtime libraries, and any other libraries you are using, along with your program.

Comment: You executed the installer in another machine and it works? It is the application who fails?

Comment: @Manuel If I do not include the .dlls, the application fails and says "missing ____.dll" for whatever files it cannot find. But when I include all the .dll files in the same directory as the .exe file, the application fails with a Gdk related error

Comment: @LiamWard can you show the error?

Comment: @Manuel Thanks for your help, the Gdk error I get when all the .dll files are included in the same directory as the .exe is "terminate called after throwing an instance of Gdk::PixbufError". However, that error doesn't show up on the original machine where I developed the application, and I have checked that all of the images I load are in the same directory as the .exe.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Is there any way to figure out exactly which files I need to include?

Comment: @LiamWard The list is too long to show here but you have one [here](http://www.tarnyko.net/repo/gtk3_build_system/tutorial/gtk3_tutorial.htm) in "Bundle content files list" section.

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch the exception and look at `Gdk::PixbufError::code()` or `Gdk::PixbufError::what()` to see why it throws.

You have several codes:

```
  CORRUPT_IMAGE,
  INSUFFICIENT_MEMORY,
  BAD_OPTION,
  UNKNOWN_TYPE,
  UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION,
  FAILED,
  INCOMPLETE_ANIMATION
```

Images in the development machine are in the same directory as the build `.exe`?

Also, if you run the app from an icon, shortcut or similar, the current directory may not be the same as the `.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me when I packaged the wrong DLL versions (I have multiple copies of GTK DLLs due to multiple apps the uses different version)

Use `ldd mygtkapp.exe` on `msys2` console/terminal to make sure [you have the correct DLL versions packaged with your app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50130668/22129922).